# Flask-SQLAlchemy: "Login failed for user" connecting to MSSQL Database. macOS

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Newbie to Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy. Attempting to connect to a remote MSSQL database.

Toolsets: 
macOS 10.13 (High Sierra)
Python3
Flask
Flask-SQLAlchemy
FreeTDS
pyodbc

If I set up a connection using a standard flask-sqlalchemy URI like this:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<servername>/<database name>?port=1433&driver=FreeTDS&tds_version=7.3'
```

I end up with this error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user '<username>'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Interestingly, if I just use a straight pyodbc connection outside of flask it works. That code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};TDS_Version=7.3;SERVER=<servername>;PORT=1433;DATABASE=<database name>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>')
```

I either need to solve the connection issue via Flask-SQLAlchemy or to know if it's possible to create the connection with the straight pyodbc.connect statement and somehow pass that into Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Thanks for any guidance or ideas.

**Update**

I have also tried:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=<servername>;DATABASE=<database name>;PORT=1433;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>;TDS_Version=7.3')

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params
```

But I get the same 'login failed' error.

Comment: The port syntax might be false: Have you tried `mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<servername>:1433/<database name>?driver=FreeTDS&tds_version=7.3` instead of appending the port with `?port=1433`

Comment: Not even sure if you need to specify a port anyway...